# Запрос в MySQL с помощью Python

Tags: python, mysql

Как решить проблему с подключением к БД MySQL?

Захожу в БД через phpMyAdmin - ввожу логин и пароль - захожу в БД, все таблицы отображаются, могу редактировать в таблицах записи через phpMyAdmin.

В phpMyAdmin пишу запрос к одной из таблиц - всё корректно выводит.
Но если написать запрос на Python, то возникает ошибка при подключении:

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'мой_айпишник' (using password: YES)")

Естественно, хост и мой_айпишник - разные.
И это не localhost.

Код запроса:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="hosthere.tech",
  user="username",
  passwd="123pasw",
  database="username"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

res = mycursor.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM 'firsttable'")

for el in res:
    print(el)
```

Не понятно, через phpMyAdmin я могу зайти в БД, а через Python - нет.
Название хоста и название БД совпадают, но из-за этого ошибки быть не может.

В интернете подобной ошибки не нашел, чтобы через python не работал, а с phpmyadmin - работал.

Comment: существует по меньшей мере [7 различных причин](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/05/fixing-a-mysql-1045-error/), по которым MySQL server может выдавать это сообщение об ошибке. Для начала сравните параметры соединения в phpMyAdmin с теми, которые вы используете в Python

Answer (score 2):

Если есть доступ к `mysql` консоли, установите права пользователю:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to username@мойайпишник identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Comment: я таблицу могу редактировать через phpMyAdmin, удалять в ней записи. Значит ошибка не в привилегиях. Но с помощью питона - не получается, вылетает ошибка, описанная выше

Comment: @Евгений ошибка вполне может быть в привилегиях, ведь доступ с вашего IP-адреса вполне может оказаться запрещён (в то время как у phpMyAdmin его IP-адрес очевидно разрешён)

Comment: @andreymal скажите, а какое указывать имя пользователя и хост при добавлении пользователя в бд? Вот нашел сайт с инструкцией, но не знаю какое имя и хост писать для привилегий: https://www.reg.ru/support/vps-servery/oblachnie-serveri-vps/ustanovka-programmnogo-obespechenija/kak-sozdat-novogo-polzovatelja-i-nastroit-prava-dostupa-v-mysql

Comment: @Евгений укажите newuser и localhost, дайте ему права на чтение (для начала) и пробуйте подключиться с именем удаленного хоста, именем этого нового пользователя и его паролем